# SignalR “signalr/hubs” showing 404 error while connecting

Tags: jquery, angularjs, signalr

I'm Implementing a SignalR Stock Ticker Using AngularJS based on an  [example over here.](https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-signalr-stock) . But while connecting to  signalr I'm  getting this error in my  console. `GET http://localhost:9000/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22stockticker%22%7D%5D&_=1480557137118 404 (Not Found)   jquery.js:9536`

Let me show the output with an image for a better clarity.

[image]

And this is the Error which is showing in  my jquery.js file.

```
try {

     // Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
     xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
     } catch ( e ) {

    // #14683: Only rethrow if this hasn't been notified as an error yet
    if ( callback ) {
    throw e;
     }
     }
```

As shown in the image the data is only  loading but couldn't find any response or the output.

Since I'm new to signalr concept , have got lots of confusion in it. So, can anybody please help me out of this ?

Comment: Show how you configured SignalR on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 404 error while connecting to signalr using Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894663/getting-404-error-while-connecting-to-signalr-using-angularjs)